# Alpine Linux PHP7 to PHP8 upgrade

Tags: alpine-linux, php7

I run a web server on Alpine Linux. Previously I used PHP7, and I wanted to upgrade to PHP8. What is the proper way to do this? I tried with
`apk del php7` and then `apk add php8`, but it looks like this does not work properly: a simple PHP test page with just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` displays the right php version, but is missing the proper formatting. Under `/var/log/apache2/error.log` I don't see php related errors, though.

Answer (score 0):

Correct procedure suggests to:

```
stop web service
purge old php version with extension
install new php version with extension
start web service
```

Correctness of this procedure depends on the way your system environment handles default configuration of installed packages. Focal point is: it is not enough to install php, also web service needs to be instructed.